# Parsing a semi-formatted file

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I've been trying to find a good way to parse a text file that I look at often. The problem is not parsing out the simple one line sections, but rather the ones that span multilines and occasionally contain characters such as `:`. The second issue is that occasionally there will be a random line before the next section that does not work as a value:key pair.

My idea (though I have not yet figured out how to code it), is that since the SECTION values are known, they could be provided in a `List<string>` and that would allow the parse to go through a section until arriving at the another value in the `List<string>`. That's what I've attempted to do with my code so far.

What I need help with is mainly figuring out the multiline issue, and secondarily storing everything in a list of dictionaries (`List<Dictionary>`) to store each section in its own dictionary (or if someone has a better idea, by all means).

**Sample Text:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

SECTION1
  VALUE1: incididunt ut labore
  VALUE2: nostrud
  VALUE3: eiusmod tempor 
  VALUE4: Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  VALUE5: Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.
SECTION2
  VALUE1: incididunt ut labore
  VALUE2: nostrud
  VALUE3: eiusmod tempor 
  VALUE4: Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  VALUE5: Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum.
```

**Sample Code:**

```
                        bool Sec1 = false;
                        bool Sec2 = false;

                        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                        {

                            if (lines[i].Equals("SECTION1") || Sec1 == true)
                            {
                                if (lines[i + 1].StartsWith("  "))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(lines[i + 1].Trim());
                                    Sec1 = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Sec1 = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (lines[i].Equals("SECTION2") || Sec2 == true)
                            {
                                if (lines[i + 1].StartsWith("  "))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(lines[i + 1].Trim());
                                    Sec2 = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Sec2 = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at YAML?

Comment: Not sure how it would work, considering my (limited) understanding of YAML is that it has a predefined syntax. I have no control over the originating format (otherwise I would have chosen something quite a bit different). The lack of multi-line characters already seems a major hurdle.

Comment: While this is beyond a reasonable use of Regex (for most of us, though a few hard-core regex-ophiles may disagree), it is also far below what would justify introducing a generalized parser generator. In these cases I simply fall back on a simple hand-written recursive descent parser, and recommend the same to you. But it does have to be a bit fancier than your sample code.

Comment: That's what I was working on with my sample code, and I would love to continue, but I've come to a mental block on how to handle anything else. That said, my disclaimer is I am no coder, I'm just trying to get past this damn bottleneck of format changes.

Comment: @Pieter I'm a hardcore regex guy, but I object to the idea of parsing HTML with it...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I'm, a softcore regex guy, and I only meant to imply that there are some who dare go where I fear to tread.

Comment: @lordzero: My Latin these days begins and ends with "Qui dolor, cui dolium" ('Who's sad with a keg', for the uninitiated.), so I will leave you to it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. At least it should give you a hint:

```
private void Parse()
{
    var Dictionary = new List<List<string>>();
    var Section = new List<string>();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(this.fileName))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() > -1) 
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine().Trim();

            if (line.StartsWith("SECTION") && Section.Count > 0)
            {
                Dictionary.Add(Section); //// Store previous section
                Section = new List<string>();
            }

            if (line.StartsWith("VALUE"))
            {
                line = line.Remove(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
                Section.Add(line.Trim());
            }
        }

        if (Section.Count > 0)
        {
            Dictionary.Add(Section); //// Store last section
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alina, I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question. I'm seeing a few problems with this though.
1) The dictionary as you use it wouldn't work (especially as it would leave  the type of the VALUE unknown. It might make more sense to create a object for each value and store that in a SECTION. This would allow for keeping multiple non-unique key-value pairs.

2) This does not help in any form with multi-line values which is my biggest problem.

3) While it seems I could have described this clearer, the VALUE in unknown and is only defined by having a : after it.